# TCL twapi Excel write: Text formatting

Tags: excel, tcl

This is strange. I am using twapi package (4.1.27, 64bit) to write data to Excel. I made cell formatting to text before I write data, still I see values like '1.23E+09' when the actual data is '1233566706'. My code below.

Similar code works fine in tcom package (32bit package), so it is not issue with the version of Excel I am using. How can I display the actual value in Excel cell? (1233566706 in this case)

```
#twapi 4.1.27
package require twapi

set excelOutFile {C:\AA\1.xlsx}

set application [::twapi::comobj Excel.Application]
set workbooks [$application Workbooks]

set workbook [$workbooks Add]
set worksheets [$workbook Worksheets]
set worksheet [$worksheets Item [expr 1]]
$worksheet Activate
set cells [$worksheet Cells]

set range [$worksheet Range "A1" "A1"]
#change format to Text
$range NumberFormat "@"

$cells Item [expr 1] [expr 1] "1233566706"

$workbook SaveAs $excelOutFile
$application Quit
$cells -destroy 
$worksheet -destroy 
$worksheets -destroy 
$workbook -destroy 
$workbooks -destroy 
$application -destroy
unset application
```

Comment: I can't test this as I don't have Office on my Windows system… but have you tried setting the number format _after_ setting the value?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. No change. in Excel, the cell A1 format is Text, it is only value not getting displayed correctly.

Comment: I have no way of testing but try adding an apostrophe ' before the text "'1233566706"

Comment: @Nir Levy, I knew about apostrophe workaround. But I am trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Your script worked for me with Tcl 8.6.8 (64-bit), TWAPI 4.1.27, and Excel 2013. By default, the cell displays "1.23E+09", but if you expand the column, it correctly shows "1233566706":

[image]

I added a call to AutoFit to do this automatically and added a call to destroy the range object, otherwise Excel wouldn't exit:

```
#twapi 4.1.27
package require twapi

set excelOutFile {C:\AA\1.xlsx}

set application [::twapi::comobj Excel.Application]
set workbooks [$application Workbooks]

set workbook [$workbooks Add]
set worksheets [$workbook Worksheets]
set worksheet [$worksheets Item [expr 1]]
$worksheet Activate
set cells [$worksheet Cells]
set columns [$worksheet Columns]

set range [$worksheet Range "A1" "A1"]
#change format to Text
$range NumberFormat "@"

$cells Item [expr 1] [expr 1] "1233566706"
$columns AutoFit

$workbook SaveAs $excelOutFile
$application Quit
$range -destroy
$columns -destroy
$cells -destroy
$worksheet -destroy
$worksheets -destroy
$workbook -destroy
$workbooks -destroy
$application -destroy
unset application
```